# rackup: command not found

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, rack, rackup

I am currently working on a project that requires the rackup command on ubuntu 11.04, but I am getting an error: `-bash: rackup: command not found`. I have installed both the rails and rack ruby gems.

Any help with this would be awesome!

Comment: some more info would help. are you using rvm? what's in your $PATH?

Comment: No, I am not using rvm and here is what my $PATH has: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`

Comment: where is your ruby installation? does `rails` command work?

Comment: Not sure where I can find out where my ruby installation is, but `rails` does work.

Comment: `which rails` should tell you where gems' binaries are located, `rackup` should be in the same location. if it's not maybe try reinstalling `rack` gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like rackup was really rackup1.8. Problem was solved right after that! Anybody who runs into a similar issue, be sure to try rackup[version] along with just rackup.

Answer (score 17):

if you're using bundler then perhaps you need to use bundle exec

```
bundle exec rackup
```

Comment: Just throwing this error when I try that: `-bash: bundle: command not found`

Comment: @ZacharyChristopoulos - Have you checked whether the Gemfile exists?